# What is minimum java version required for Spring Boot 1.4.x

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a web service using spring boot 1.4.x and deploying it in Websphere 8.5 which supports java 6.But when I deploy my war in WAS i am getting below error.

Looks like one of jar dependency(spring-ws-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar) in Spring boot have classes compiled with java 7.Which is causing below error.

What is minimum java version required to use Spring Boot 1.4.x?
In my case is it possible to overwrite above dependency alone to lower version?

Error:

```
 2/16/17 10:58:08:296 EST] 000000f2 CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=testpp-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=testpp-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT_war failed to start.
[2/16/17 10:58:08:299 EST] 000000f2 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=MyNode,version=8.5.5.2,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=MyCell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMCFRE003 bad major version&amp;#59&#59; class=org/springframework/ws/transport/http/support/AbstractMessageDispatcherServletInitializer, offset=6
[2/16/17 10:58:08:299 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: JVMCFRE003 bad major version&amp;#59&#59; class=org/springframework/ws/transport/http/support/AbstractMessageDispatcherServletInitializer, offset=6
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:432)
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
[2/16/17 10:58:08:300 EST] 000000f2 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
```

**POM Configuration**

testap
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements):

> By default, Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE requires Java 7 and Spring Framework 4.3.6.RELEASE or above. You can use Spring Boot with Java 6 with some additional configuration. See [Section 81.11, “How to use Java 6”](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-java-6) for more details. Explicit build support is provided for Maven (3.2+) and Gradle (1.12 or 2.x). Support for Gradle 2.8 and earlier is deprecated. Gradle 3 is not supported.

The dependency you're having problems with is not Spring Boot but the separate [Spring Web Services which is only compatible with Java 7](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d5e65):

> Spring Web Services requires a standard Java 7 Runtime Environment. Java 8 is also supported. Spring-WS is built on Spring Framework 4.0.9, but higher versions are supported.

You could try to downgrade or exclude the dependency but there's a high risk that you break something.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.So its always advisable use java 7 if we go with Spring Boot 1.4.